# Sunspot + Solr 5.2 (latest)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I don't know where to put this, I can move it to Stack Overflow if you want.

I'm new at Sunspot and Rails, and I have use it before with Solr 4.X running over Tomcat7 without issues, I was happy.
Now, I'm deploying a new app, and I want to use Solr 5.2 which is the latest, this one doesn't run on top of Tomcat like his predecessors, it's now a nice standalone service running on top of a jetty instance.

So, I followed this guid to install it https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04

I have even creating a collection and stuff, but when I do `rake sunspot:reindex` it returned the following error:

`RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request Error: {'responseHeader'=>{'status'=>400,'QTime'=>127},'error'=>{'msg'=>'undefined field type','code'=>400}} URI: http://localhost:8983/solr/screencap-dev/update?wt=ruby Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"} Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:[MODEL NAME]</query></delete>"`

That [MODEL NAME] is the name of the model I'm indexing.

I can't make it work, so I'm using the sunspot_solr version, I even tried to move every config file over to my Solr 5.2 without success, Server errors and stuff.

Did anyone did this already?

**UPDATE**

I have tried to copy the collection files from sunspot_solr (Solr 5.0.0) to my Solr Service (Solr 5.2.0), I got it to load the files, but:

`Error CREATEing SolrCore 'screencap-dev': Unable to create core [screencap-dev] Caused by: solr.DateField`

Obviously Sunspot collections files are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Your solr instance is broken.

These are the terminal commands you should follow to solve your problems:

1. ps aux | grep solr to get solr process ID
2. sudo kill ,  is the ID you found from 1
3. rm -r , remove the solr directory inside your project
   to
4. remove all of previous indexes
5. RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
6. Change the path to /solr/default inside config/sunspot.yml
7. RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex

Comment: I did that. The thing is, if you don't create a collection first (you can do it in the terminal with `sudo su - solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c gettingstarted -n data_driven_schema_configs"`) it will returns you 404 Not Found, because there is no collections. 
So let's say you created one, and then you change your sunspot.yml to point to the correct instance and all, the reindex shows that error.

Comment: please try to remove and reinstall sunspot again. what is your sunspot gem version?